# Use sublime as my SSH client

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there a way I can use my text editor, sublime text as an SSH client. A replacement for PuTTy.

It seems like a great plugin and I'd imagine someone must've already thought of this and made it.

Comment: You say  *it*, what is that? There is [Sublime SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) but I have never used it personally

Comment: no no not the SFTP. I want to be able to use sublime text as my terminal window.

Comment: This is only possible in OSX if i recall correctly

Comment: and which extension is that?

Comment: @sublime, i don't understand your question. Apple OSX has  a built in terminal, so nothing is needed